# scala will choose which method when both use default parameters and polymorphism?

Tags: scala

I have writen a simple prog:

```
object A extends App{

 def a(b:String,c:String="")=println("a")
 def a(b:String)=println("b")

 a("a")
}
```

this prog will print b,but print a is also right as the grammar

so scala will choose which method when both use default parameters and polymorphism?

Comment: The compiler picks the most specific one, whenever or not that is a good idea depends on who you ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler's algorithm is in effect, for this (if after any step there are no alternatives, it is an error):

- Choose the members of `A` named `a` (so `a: (String, String) => Unit` and `a: String => Unit`)
- Eliminate ones which aren't applicable with the shape; both are applicable (the one which takes two `String`s is applicable because the second `String` has a default argument)
- If there's a single member left which is applicable, that is the one which is chosen
- Otherwise, *eliminate any applicable alternatives which use a default argument* (so only `a: String => Unit` remains)
- If there is a most specific alternative (meaning more specific than all other remaining alternatives), that is the one which is chosen
- Otherwise it is an error

Basically, default arguments effectively only matter if they are the only way to get a function application to work.